# Tried to add innerhtml by tagname or by id but its didn't shown effect

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add innerHtml of element named as P.I had added its attribute id which has value p1. And i had tried to changes it innerhtml while onclick of a button.But overall i am failed to do so. And i still have no idea why its not doing so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>javascript </title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myfunction()">click me</button>
<p id="new"> this my content added by manully</p>
<p id="p1"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("new").innerHtml="this is my first page";
    function myfunction(){
        //alert(1);
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHtml="this is my first page";
        //console.log();
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am following this example which is showing results successfully.Please have an eye on it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function that will output "Hello World" in a p element with id="demo".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: innerHtml doesn't exist...use innerHTML. js is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using wrong syntax of javascript function which is named as innerHTML but i was using it as innerHtml.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>javascript </title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myfunction()">click me</button>
<p id="new"> this my content added by manully</p>
<p id="p1"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML="this is my first page";
    function myfunction(){
        //alert(1);
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="this is my first page";
        //console.log();


    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<script>
        $(document).on('click', '#new', function () {

            $(this).html('my msg');

        })
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks but i want to use only javascript i have no idea about jquery till now.

Comment: your welcome , but it dosent need to be professional at JQUERY just add it's link to head of your html doc  ;)